# Variable name as Column in Sql Server 2012 WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I've tried a variety of methods, and this is one I was sure would work -- but the alter storedprocedure fails at the CASE line.

```
     WHERE v.State_combined != ''

    CASE WHEN @component = 'Component 1' 
        THEN
        AND (v.[Component_1_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED')) 
        WHEN @component = 'Component 2' 
        THEN
        AND (v.[Component_2_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED'))
        ELSE
        AND (v.[Component_1_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED') or       v.[Component_2_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED'))
        END

    AND (@state IS null OR v.STATE_COMBINED = @state)
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: CASE is not for control-of-flow; its an expression that must return a value ...

Comment: THEN AND is incorrect syntax for CASE. You need THEN something AND or leave the AND out completely.

Comment: Use the form; `WHERE X AND (@component = 'Component 1' AND ...)`

Comment: I've added quotes around the 'and' statement as in: 'AND (v.[Component_1_Status] IN (''SUBMITTED'', ''INCOMPLETE'', ''PURCHASED''))'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you want to achieve? There could be more different solutions. Share the table's structure, some example values, the expected result and your goal with us. (A good practice is to create an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) demo with the structure and exmple values.)

Comment: I'm trying to use a variable as a column name within the where clause.  It's easy to use the variable as a value, but here I know the possible values.  I just don't know the column they are wanting to base their results on.

Answer (score 1):

Example solution with `CASE..WHEN`

```
WHERE
    v.State_combined != ''
    AND 1 = CASE
        WHEN @component = 'Component 1' AND (v.[Component_1_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED')) THEN 1
        WHEN @component = 'Component 2' AND (v.[Component_2_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED')) THEN 1
        WHEN (
            v.[Component_1_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED')
            OR v.[Component_2_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED')
        ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
END
AND (@state IS null OR v.STATE_COMBINED = @state)
```

The `CASE..WHEN` will return a value, you can not use it as a control structure.

Another solution (boolen logic only):

```
WHERE
    v.State_combined != ''
    AND (
        (@component = 'Component 1' AND v.[Component_1_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED'))
        OR (@component = 'Component 2' AND v.[Component_2_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED'))
        OR (
            @component NOT IN ('Component 1', 'Component 2')
            AND (
                v.[Component_1_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED')
                OR v.[Component_2_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED')
            )
        )
    )
    AND (@state IS null OR v.STATE_COMBINED = @state)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I've been fighting this for hours.  I'm not a DBA or SQL Developer and you guys have been so helpful.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE  v.State_combined != ''
       AND
       (
           (
               @component = 'Component 1' 
               AND 
               v.[Component_1_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED')
           ) 
           OR
           (
               @component = 'Component 2' 
               AND 
               v.[Component_2_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED')
           )
           OR
           (
               v.[Component_1_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED') 
               OR       
               v.[Component_2_Status] IN ('SUBMITTED', 'INCOMPLETE', 'PURCHASED')
           )
       )
       AND 
       (
           @state IS NULL 
           OR 
           v.STATE_COMBINED = @state
       )
```

Comment: In the last part of the component check you should check that `@component` is not `'Component 1'` neither `'Component 2'`. Without that, the logic will evaulate to true when `@component = 'Component 1'` and `Component_2_Status = 'SUBMITTED'`

Comment: True, but that's the OP's logic.  That could be how they wanted it.  We aren't really sure what the intent is here.  I was just showing how to get the WHERE clause to a working order.